# Inner working of HTML?

Tags: html, compilation

How does HTML work? Does it get parsed, compiled and then executed? Does it get converted to a high level language like `C`, `C++`, `Python`, `Java', then the C code gets compiled and executed?

If this is the case then, why can't we keep a code that is very close to architectural code, which can be interpreted by a virtual machine, as compiling and parsing has `n^3` complexity.

If this is not the case then how does it work. How do browsers work?

Comment: I think you're heading in the wrong direction with this. It is better to think of [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) as a [markup language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language) rather than a [programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language). It just represents the elements on a webpage and how they are organized relative to each other (you might want to look up [DOM](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/default.asp)). Basically, the client makes a request to the server, the server sends an HTML page, the browser reads it and displays it to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does html work?? Does it get parsed, compiled and then executed?? Does it get converted to a high level language like C,C++, like python,java; then the c code gets compiled and executed.

None of those.  It is parsed by the web browser and turned into (browser specific) internal data structures that are not source-code of any programming language.  The browser then computes a screen layout and paints the screen based on that data structure.  The component of the web browser that does this is known as the rendering engine; e.g. WebKit and Gecko are examples.

The details are complicated, but many web browsers are open source so you can examine the source-code to see what is really going on.